# Prove or disprove if $K=L$ then $K'=L'$, where $M=K\oplus K'=L\oplus L'$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $M=K\oplus K'=L\oplus L'$ be direct sums of submodules of $M$.
>
> Prove or disprove if $K=L$ then $K'=L'$.
>
> If not, give rationales. And then show that $K'\cong L'$.

**Approach**

Actually, it's not true, $K'=L'$.

I found a counter example, consider $M=\mathbb R^2$, and let $K=L=\left\{(x,0)|\quad x\in\mathbb R\right\}$.

And let $K'=\left\{(0,y)|\quad y\in\mathbb R\right\}$ and $L'=\left\{(z,z)|\quad z\in\mathbb R\right\}$.

Then $K'\cong L'$ but not $K'=L'$.

My question is the second part.

How can I prove $K'\cong L'$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$M/K\simeq K'$ and similarly $M/L\simeq L'$. When $K=L$ you get what you want.

Comment: OOOHH, very clear thank you!